# Reload page js after database query in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I have such script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#requestTable').DataTable(
        {
            aoColumns: [
            { mDataProp: "DateStart", sTitle: "Date Start" },
            { mDataProp: "DateEnd", sTitle: "Date End" },
            { mDataProp: "Approved", sTitle: "Approved" },
            { mDataProp: "Data", sTitle: "Employee" },
            { mDataProp: "Position", sTitle: "Position" },
            { mDataProp: "", sTitle: "" }
            ],
            columnDefs: [{
                targets: 'no-sort',
                orderable: false
            }]
        });

    $('button.accept-button').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id')        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TableRequest/AcceptRequest",
            data: { 'id': id },
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
        location.reload(true);
    });
    var tempId;
    $('button.decline-button').click(function () {
        tempId = $(this).attr('data-id')
        $("#dialog").dialog()
    });
    $('button.ok-request').click(function () {
        var message = $('textarea#commentForDecline').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TableRequest/DeclineRequest",
            data: { 'message': message, 'id': tempId },
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
        $("#dialog").dialog('close');
        $('textarea#commentForDecline').val('');
        location.reload(true);
    });
});
```

As you can see I reload page after post Ajax query. But is there any way to check changes in Db and refresh page after this (call the `Action`)? So Db changes is late and I wanna to check it.

Comment: I'm not very sure on what are you asking exactly, but you can check whatever you want in DB with a similar ajax call and then depending on result you can do page reload. Example:
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/SomeDBCheck",
            data: { 'someData': data },
            success: function (msg) {
                 if(msg.reload)
                      location.reload(true);
            }
        });

Comment: Is this ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 2):

You can reload the page after success, and from backend action return the data you want to check and after you can reload

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.somekey === "somevalue"){
        location.reload(true);
    } else {
        //don't reload show me some erros
    }

}
```